# Spring MVC RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Did not find handler method

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I think my configuration is ok but I keep getting the same error "Did not find handler method".

The error:

```
10:55:46.284 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /WEB-INF/views/html/products/list.html
10:55:46.285 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Did not find handler method for [/WEB-INF/views/html/products/list.html]
10:55:46.285 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] WARN org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/store/WEB-INF/views/html/products/list.html] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring-web'
10:55:46.285 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
```

My web.xml is as below:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring-web</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-web</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

My spring-web-servlet.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.ecommerce.config" />
```

My SprinWebConfig.java

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({ "com.ecommerce.web", "com.ecommerce.service", "com.ecommerce.dao", "com.ecommerce.exception", "com.ecommerce.validator" })
public class SpringWebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/html/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource rb = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        rb.setBasenames(new String[] {"messages/messages", "messages/validation"});
        return rb;
    }
}
```

ProductController.java

```
@Controller
public class ProductController {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProductController.class);

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String index(Model model) {
        logger.debug("index()");
        return "redirect:/products";
    }

    @GetMapping("/products")
    public String showAllProducts(Model model) {
        logger.debug("showAllProducts()");

        //Here I'm constructing a list named products

        model.addAttribute("products", products);

        return "products/list";
    }
}
```

So, I can't see where is my problem. Can you help please? thanks

Comment: You've defined an InternalResourceViewResolver. So for 'list' view: prefix + view name + suffix = /WEB-INF/views/html/list.html. what happens when you call the url (/list)? Do you have a Controller for /list?

Comment: Sorry @awagenhoffer I forgot to add my controller. See it now and tell me what you think please. Thank you

Comment: like awagenhoffer said: you don't have a method is mapped to the URL in the error. you need a `@GetMapping("/list")` method.

Comment: @Jack Flamp thank you I'll try that